# vba "run-time error 1004: Method 'Paste' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: vba

I am trying to paste only from the non empty rows. The error is in line 6. If someone could help me I would really appreciate it because I am stucked with this and I don't kow how to fix it.

```
   Public Sub read_truefalse()
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim path As String
    
    path = Sheet5.Cells(3, 1).Value
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(path, ReadOnly:=True)

    Dim i As Long
    i = 0
    Dim wPara As Word.Paragraph
    Dim last As Integer

...
     Sheet 7.Activate

   1 For Each wPara In wDoc.Paragraphs
   2    If wPara.Range.Words.Count > 1 Then
   3         last = wPara.Range.Words.Count
   4         wPara.Range.Copy
   5         Sheet7.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Activate
   6         Sheet7.Paste
   7         i = i + 1

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Public Sub read_truefalse()
    
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document, wPara As Word.Paragraph
    Dim path As String
    Dim i As Long, last As Long
    
    path = Sheet5.Cells(3, 1).Value
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(path, ReadOnly:=True)

    For Each wPara In wDoc.Paragraphs
       If wPara.Range.Words.Count > 1 Then
            i = i + 1
            last = wPara.Range.Words.Count '??
            wPara.Range.Copy
            With Sheet7
                .Paste Destination:=.Cells(i, "A") 'no need to select to paste
            End With
        End If
    Next wPara

    'clean up...
    wDoc.Close False
    wApp.Quit
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your time and your help! I tried what you said and I'm still getting the same error, now it fails in ".Paste Destination:=..."

Comment: Worked fine for me - is your worksheet protected?  How much text are you trying to paste?